# R - Find partially matching tuples

Tags: r

Assuming you have a data frame as follows:

```
column1   column2    column3    column4
   1        124         2          a
   2        125         4          b
   3        124         6          c
   4        126         8          d
   5        150         10         e
```

What is the most efficient (i.e. fastest) way to just find out (TRUE/FALSE) if the data frame contains any tuples that satisfy conditions based on only TWO of the columns?

How would you go about finding out (w/o a loop) if there is a tuple that satisfy the conditions `column1==1 & column2<140 & column2>130`?  (Of course, the result would have to return `FALSE` in such a case).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @Tomas points out - you were almost there:

```
any(df$column1==1 & df$column2<140 & df$column2>130)
#[1] FALSE
```

or...

```
with(df,any(column1==1 & column2<140 & column2>130))
#[1] FALSE
```

Comment: +1 for use of "any" function--didn't know about that! Very useful!

Comment: +1 for elegant solution with `any`, this answer is probably more exactly suited to the question.

Answer (score 2):

Almost exactly as you wrote:

```
df[df$column1==1 & df$column2<140 & df$column2>130,]
```

or

```
with(df, df[column1==1 & column2<140 & column2>130,])
```

Answer (score 2):

Or using `data.table` and `between` syntax sugar:

```
library(data.table)
DT <- data.table(dat)
DT[column1==1 & column2 %between% c(130,140)]
```

Comment: agstudy, you have to use `DT$column1`, right? Or is this another "syntax sugar"? :-)

Comment: @Tomas - `data.table`'s allow you to access variables without the `$` notation.

Comment: interesting! Would love this in standard R because having to write `df$` over and over is endlessly anoying. +1 for the syntax sugar!